# How to limit the Relation Elements of a Class in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have

```
class User {
  String name

  hasMany = [books: Book]
}


class Book (
  String name
  belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

Now, I can access all books of a user instance as:

```
def user = User.find("someId")
println user.books
```

How can I limit the number of books such that I get only the first x books from user.books?
Is there also a way to sort them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One viable approach is to define `books` as `List` inside `User`. You would need to have an index column but you could get the benefit of pagination and ordering like:

```
class User{
    List books
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

def user = User.find("someId")
println user.books?.getAt(3..10).sort{it.name}
```

**Note:-**
**All** books for User will be fetched lazily, using the above approach will filter books from index 3 till 10.

In case you want to optimize the lazy fetch strategy (N + 1), then you would probably need to have a look at [batchSize](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/batchSize.html) and [order](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/order.html). Also [sort](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html) as a side note.

Example:

```
class User {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
  static mapping = {
      books batchSize: 10
  }
}

class Book (
  String name
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
  static mapping = {
      order "desc"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is better to set the order in the Book class in mappings or for the books relation in the User class?

Comment: @confile Setting order in `Book` will always fetch books in order no matter you fetch it via `User` or directly from `Book`. If you want fine grained approach to sort books only in case of User then you can go with the later approach. Also have a look at my updated answer. `batchSize` would only optimize the N + 1 problem but it will not return paginated results.

Comment: How would you do pagination in your second case?

Comment: @confile You can use the former approach here as well. Using books as List. The only difference in the second approach is that while lazily fetching books for a user it would fetch in batches of 10 instead of fetching it one by one. Hence, optimize N + 1 problem.

Comment: @confile One useful tip: If you do not worry abut performance and/or user has comparatively less number of books (for ex: 10, 50 or 100) then you can use criteria usefully to fetch all books eagerly. Using projections you can get the desired number of books. One interesting fact is if you are familiar with criteria then you would like playing around with [namedQueries](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html). I like it when I wan't to fetch associations eagerly.

Comment: How do I know which batch size is correct? I.e., which one is to high?